# Permissions - Make this the default view

Tags: 2013, permissions, list-view

We would like to have personal views for each user in SP2013. Every user needs a different field order and we can not use default view for all of them. Of course we can create new views and each time press the button to load that view up. But is it possible to make default view be really default without loading it up by pressing the button?

As I can see from the admin account - there is an option when creating a personal view

> "Make this the default view (Applies to public views only)"

After we press it, it looks like it's working as we would like it to, however there is no such option in SharePoint Members Group where all other users are added.

What permissions are missing?

Comment: Why would you want to create a uniqe view for all users?

Comment: Problem is that every employee needs to see different metadata fields, we have around 20 of these fields so what is important for accountant is not important for office administrator at all. It's quite hard each time to scroll  to see required metadata field. We would like that created personal view could load instantly every time for that particular employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matas,

If you want personal views to be loaded by default, you need to add the following line to the page header:

```
<meta name="WebPartPageDefaultViewPersonal"/>
```

With this tag in place, your page will always default to a personal view for that user. If a personal view is not set, the page will load the default view of the list.

Hope this helps.